# How filter chain invocation works?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I am trying to understand filter chaining.As defined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057607/what-is-dofilter-doing-in-dofilter-method-in-filters-of-java)

> All filters are chained (in the order of their definition in web.xml).
>   The chain.doFilter() is proceeding to the next element in the chain.
>   The last element of the chain is the target resource/servlet.

I am interested to know behind the scene in container that how container handles filter chaining.Can someone explain that how Filter chaining is handled inside container?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*Each filter implements the `javax.servlet.Filter` interface, which includes a `doFilter()` method that takes as input a `request` and `response` `pair along with a filter chain`, which is an instance of a class (provided by the servlet container) that implements the `javax.servlet.FilterChain` interface. The filter chain reflects the order of the filters. `The servlet container`, based on the configuration order in the `web.xml` file, constructs the chain of `filters` for any `servlet` or other resource that has `filters` mapped to it. For each filter in the chain, the filter chain object passed to it represents the remaining filters to be called, in order, followed by the target servlet.*

**If there are two `filters`, for example, the key steps of this mechanism would be as follows:**

[image]

*1.The target `servlet` is requested. The `container` detects that there are two `filters` and creates the `filter chain`.*

*2.The first `filter` in the chain is invoked by its `doFilter()` method.*

*3.The first `filter` completes any preprocessing, then calls the `doFilter()` method of the `filter chain`. This results in the second `filter` being invoked by its `doFilter()` method.*

*4.The second `filter` completes any preprocessing, then calls the `doFilter()` method of the `filter chain`. This results in the target `servlet` being invoked by its `service()` method.*

*5.When the target `servlet` is finished, the chain `doFilter()` call in the second `filter` returns, and the second `filter` can do any postprocessing.*

*6.When the second `filter` is finished, the chain `doFilter()` call in the first `filter` returns, and the first `filter` can do any postprocessing.*

*7.When the first `filter` is finished, execution is complete.*

Filters can be interposed between servlets and the servlet container to wrap and preprocess requests or to wrap and postprocess responses. None of the filters are aware of their order. Ordering is handled entirely through the filter chain, according to the order in which filters are configured in web.xml