# Servlet Filter not functioning properly

Tags: java, servlet-filters

After some research and trial error, I've found a [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192834/how-to-add-filters-to-servlet-without-modifying-web-xml) that would allow me to add servlet filters programmatically while preserving their order as desired without using web.xml and annotations.  Based upon the method found, the filters aren't functioning as I've understand it represented by the [picture in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196867/how-filter-chain-invocation-works).  From my logs, steps 5, 6, & 7 of filter-chain invocation never executed.

On successful web app context startup:

```
GodFilter.init
Filter1.init
Filter2.init
...
FilterFinal.init
```

When browsing the web app:

```
GodFilter.doFilter
Filter1.doFilter
GodFilterChain.doFilter
Filter2.doFilter
GodFilterChain.doFilter
...
FilterFinal.dofilter
MyServlet.service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
MyServlet.service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
MyServlet.getLastModified
MyServlet.doGet
```

At the very minimum, I'm expecting to see `GodFilter.doFilter` (per steps 5, 6, & 7 of filter-chain invocation) after the `MyServlet.doGet` but it's not showing up.  Am I missing something or misunderstood how servlet filter-chain works? Is the `GodFilter` class incorrect?

TIA!

[Edit 1]

I forgot to mention that the `GodFilter` is loaded via a class implementing `ServletContainerInitializer`:

```
FilterRegistration fr = context.addFilter(GodFilter.class.getSimpleName(), GodFilter.class);
fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of( //
        DispatcherType.ASYNC, //
        DispatcherType.ERROR, //
        DispatcherType.FORWARD, //
        DispatcherType.INCLUDE, //
        DispatcherType.REQUEST), false, "/*");
fr.setInitParameter("param1", "value1");
```

I've tried `isMatchedAfter` to true also but no changes.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing some more of my code for the Filters, I found I left out the crucial part of post `chain.doFilter(request, response)` processing in the `Filter.doFilter`:

```
Filter1.doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    // pre chain processing 

    // if filter is last in filter chain, then mapped servlet will process hereafter
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

    // post chain processing
}
```