# Will the code be executed after chain.doFilter()?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I am studying `javax.servlet.Filter` recently and I am confused with if the code will be executed after `chain.doFilter`.

Because of the filter chain is a single-thread chain, I guess the code will not be executed am I right?

For example :

```
chain.doFilter(req, resp);
return;
```

If the return is useless ? I also wonder where can the filter return ?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? How do you think your code runs if nothing is calling it?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057607/what-is-dofilter-doing-in-dofilter-method-in-filters-of-java